# How Can I Programmatically Build a Multi-Page TIFF out of Many Single Page TIFFs, Using Python?

Tags: python, tiff

I've found, via Google, numerous people asking the same question, but no solutions.  The Python Image Library (PIL) has tools for stepping through an already existing multi-page TIFF, but nothing about creating them.

Libraries would hopefully be available on Windows, for Python 2.6.

If there's some freeware out there which will do the trick, I wouldn't mind seeing it, but I was hoping I could accomplish this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A freeware option: `Irfanview` can do it, even via the command line; this allows you to call it from Python.

From changes version 3.90:

New command line option:

```
/multitif=(tifname,file1,...,fileN)
```

Example to create multipage TIF `test.tif` from 2 other files:

```
i_view32 /multitif=(c:\test.tif,c:\test1.bmp,c:\dummy.jpg)
```

New command line option:

```
/append=tiffile
```

Example to open `c:\test.jpg` and append it as (TIF) page to `c:\test.tif`

```
i_view32 c:\test.jpg /append=c:\test.tif
```

I have used it once and know it works, though limitation on command line length apply.

Comment: +1 for mentioning command line length limitation - also the command-line will become awkward anyway - for, say, 700+ images. also i remember having a problem with the IrfanView GUI window popping out on each image - i am not sure if this still happens

Comment: @hello_earth Use the /killmesoftly /silent switches to keep the GUI from showing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ImageMagick for this (available on Unix and Windows).
A linux shell command would be

```
$ convert *.tif multipage.tif
```

where *.tif are all your individual tif files.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the command utility "tiffutil"