# Creating a multi-page TIFF with Python

Tags: python, linux, tiff

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916769/how-can-i-programmatically-build-a-multi-page-tiff-out-of-many-single-page-tiffs), but I was looking for a solution that would work on Linux.. Is [tiffcp](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tiffcp.htm) the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do it.  The solution is essentially the same; call it from the command line.

Specifically, you want the [-adjoin](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#adjoin) option (which is on by default).  The command will look something like:

```
convert *.tiff my_combined_file.tiff
```

Comment: -1 this will only work for a small number of tiff files, and as the number of the combined tiff grows, each add will be slower and slower - IM seems to read the whole TIF and to write it back again appended - see IM can not append to an existing image file format.
see http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14590

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it, but there is [pylibtiff](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/), a python wrapper for the libtiff library on which `tiffcp` is implemented.

Comment: I ended up using ImageMagick, since my application already depends on it.. Thanks all the same for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but `convert` has the drawback that it recompresses the images.  You can use the python `tifftools` package to do this without recompressing the images: `tifftools merge *.tiff combined_file.tiff`.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `tifftools` package.