# Add multiple pages to new PDF using PIL/Pillow

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, python-imaging-library

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#pdf

The Pillow docs mention being able to save multiple pages, but I can't find any other docs or code samples that tell you how to add pages to a new PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem like this is currently possible with Pillow, I used reportlab to build a multi-page PDF from scratch:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
im.save('test.pdf', save_all=True)
```

By default, the output format is determined by the file extension. This is documented in the [release notes](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/releasenotes/3.0.0.html#saving-multipage-images).

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question. I need to know how to *add* pages.

Comment: You are not alone, this has been asked before - see [How Can I Programmatically Build a Multi-Page TIFF out of Many Single Page TIFFs, Using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916769/how-can-i-programmatically-build-a-multi-page-tiff-out-of-many-single-page-tiffs)