# Multiframe PIL.Image from a list of np.array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'd like to create a multiframe PIL.Image from a list of np.arrays and to save it with the option `save_all` (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#tiff) to create a multiframe tiff file.

I did not manage to find a way to add a frame to an PIL.Image (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html).

Related questions:

- [PIL(low) and multi-page TIFFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26660415/pillow-and-multi-page-tiffs)
- [Add multiple pages to new PDF using PIL/Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34036886/add-multiple-pages-to-new-pdf-using-pil-pillow)

Remark:

If `myfile.tiff` is a multiframe tiff file, `PIL.Image('myfile.tiff')` returns a PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile object. But how can we produce a PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile object from a list of np.arrays?